# How to create a class that may use one of two namespaces?

Tags: c#, graph, using

I have a project which contains a class that draws on a graph. The class looks like this:-

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static void DrawOnGraph (Chart ourChart,
                                        // ...more parameters...
                                        )
        {
            ChartArea our_area = new ChartArea("Main");
            // Draw things
        }
    }
}
```

This is driven by a web application contained in another project in the same solution. I now have a requirement to create a forms application which will draw precisely the same graph using precisely the same inputs on to a web form. I wish include the project into a second solution. But the class needs to look like this:-

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class Utilities
    {
        public static void DrawOnGraph (Chart ourChart,
                                        // ...more parameters...
                                        )
        {
            ChartArea our_area = new ChartArea("Main");
            // Draw things
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to know if it would be possible to use the same project/class/code for both, as naturally I don't want to cut'n'paste the code into two different places, and the only difference is the `using` directive.

I don't see how I can use generics as there are declarations inside the function of objects in the (alternative) namespaces, such as the ChartArea shown above. I can't see a way to use conditional compilation as which line is required depends on which solution the project is in, not the project itself, and it can't refer to the caller project as that would create a circular reference. Neither can I cast a web graph to a windows graph.

The best I have been able to manage is to supply both `using` directives but comment one of them out according to which solution I am currently working on. But that doesn't seem very satisfactory to me. Is there a better way? Or should I not be so idle and write the code twice?

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own abstraction on top of drawing logic and use wrapper pattern to encapsulate both charts. Then you would code against your abstraction and provide implementation form each forms and web project. I assume the drawing graph logic in complicated enough to justify this approach. If you implement this it will allow you to introduce changes in graph in one place and it will affect both applications.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but if I do this, won't I end up with two sets of class definitions which differ only by the `using` directive?

Comment: Basically yes but those classes will be very strait forward and wont contain any logic just forward parameters to winforms or web implementation. All your logic will be held in separate class that invokes you facade.

Answer (score 2):

The best soultion I can think of is to create wrapper-interfaces for classes, that both `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` and `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` provide/require. Then provide two implementations of the interface: one for Forms and one for UI. Having that, your `Utilities` can call interface methods without knowing the exact implementation, and share code for both UI and Forms.

Answer (score 1):

One is for Web

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

and the other one for windows

```
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

the issue is that they will be using classes that are relevant for their platform so I don think you able to achieve it

My advice would be to separate out the common functionality in to a library which is not dependant for Web or Windows and use this in to two different solution one for web and the other for windows, this way alteast you have reduced the code repetition twice

**Update :**

Another option is to write it as Windows Control library and then make it available in the web application as a DLL. Please look at this example http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Place-Windows-Control-To-Web-Form.aspx

Comment: thank you for your answer, but sadly more or less everything in the function uses a graph-related object of some sort.

Comment: @BrianHooper just out of curiosity is their a major difference in the UI ouput from both of these namespaces

Comment: @BrianHooper please see my updated answer this might help you

Comment: I'll have a look at that, thank you. The graphs in the two applications are identical. The rest of the form/page isn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***conditional compilation*** if your code calls the 'identical' parts of the respective APIs of Web.UI and Windows.Forms Charting, that include operations with Series, ChartArea, etc.

Simply compile the code twice:  once ***using*** Web.UI Charting and the other ***using*** Windows.Forms Charting. Use conditional compilation to enable/disable assembly references so one assembly targets applications based on WinForms and the other WebUI Charting apps.

Alternatively, in some quick-and-dirty situations you could get by with just the Windows.Forms Charting API, and whenever html is needed, e.g. a ***src*** attribute for an ***img*** element, merely use ***Chart.SaveImage***(..), and so on.  But this has drawbacks.

Both of these alternatives are limiting because the respective APIs and functionalities of Web.UI and Windows.Forms Charting don't overlap enough. And SaveImage() is additionally limiting because you don't want your web app burdened by the Windows.Forms assemblies and extraneous operations.

Nonetheless the conditional compilation approach will work even if the web and forms assemblies diverge.  You will be able to maintain shared codes (but conditionally compiled for web or forms), but each library will accumulate new code specific to its web or forms target.  This approach works best with a good approach to build configuration.  If you have a good approach to build configuration I think it will be easier to maintain and extend than other approaches.